# Label-text: How to insert a SPACE before end of line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Simplified code:

```
label.set_text(ID, 'something' + str.tostring(aVariable) + '\t\n')    //no space appears
label.set_text(ID, 'something' + str.tostring(aVariable) + '\t\t\n')  //no spaces appears
label.set_text(ID, 'something' + str.tostring(aVariable) + '\tA\t\n') //' A' appears but no space before the end of line.
```

This bagatell thing is useful when we display multiple lines in a label (with calculated data values) and we may need a space at the end of line to format the label.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is best practice, but I'd use [zero-width spaces](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) for this purpose. You can try add U+200B at the end of "\t"s.